# Why is the function calling again?

Tags: python

I am trying to merge the K-sorted linked lists [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/). The code runs fine until somehow it calls the function smallest node with ('head', ListNode{val: 0, next: None}) and ('options', [None]). The test case is a list of nodes that look like this: 1->4->5, 1->3->4, 2->6. Please help me find out why is it doing this and how I can fix it, There's clearly something I am missing.

Here's my code:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution(object):
    def mergeKLists(self, lists):
        """
        :type lists: List[ListNode]
        :rtype: ListNode
        """

        temp = ListNode()

        def smallest_node(head, options):

            if len(options) > 0:
                print("head", head)
                print("options", options)

                lowest = min(options, key=attrgetter('val'))
                options.remove(lowest)
                print("options here", options)

                head.next = lowest
                
                if lowest.next:
                    options.append(lowest.next)

                print("and options here", options)
                print("and lowest", lowest)

                
                
                smallest_node(lowest, options)


        smallest_node(temp, lists)

        return temp.next
```

Here's the error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'lowest =
min(options, key=attrgetter('val'))Line 21 in smallest_node 
(Solution.py)smallest_node(temp, lists)Line 38 in mergeKLists
 (Solution.py)ret = Solution().mergeKLists(param_1)Line 59 in _driver 
(Solution.py)_driver()Line 69 in <module> (Solution.py)
```

Here's the print log:

```
('head', ListNode{val: 4, next: None})('options', [ListNode{val: 6, 
next: None}, ListNode{val: 5, next: None}])('options here', 
[ListNode{val: 6, next: None}])('and options here', [ListNode{val: 6, 
next: None}])('and lowest', ListNode{val: 5, next: None})('head', 
ListNode{val: 5, next: None})('options', [ListNode{val: 6, next: 
None}])('options here', [])('and options here', [])('and lowest', 
ListNode{val: 6, next: None})('head', ListNode{val: 0, next: None})
('options', [None])
```

I have tried debugging this with print statements and I can not figure out why the function is being called with the mentioned values of head and options.

Comment: if you read the comments on that leet code question, there's people remarking that inputs such as `[None] - written as "[[]]"` and `[(2,None),None,(0,None)] - written as "[[2],[],[0]]"`